# Package management in RStudio Connect

Tags: r, rstudio-server

I have recently started using both RStudio Connect and the RStudio Package manager.

I came across [this short page](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/226871467-Package-management-in-RStudio-Connect) from RStudio that says "You can integrate RStudio Package Manager with both RStudio Server Pro and RStudio Connect for a seamless experience with your R packages.".

Is there some specific documentation or an example? I'm a bit confused about what this means and how the package manager will work with the packrat and rsconnect packages that are used when deploying applications.

If it is relevant to consider, I plan on primarily deploying shiny apps to Connect using the API with scripts similar to the ones that appear in this repo: https://github.com/rstudio/connect-api-deploy-shiny/tree/master/deploy

Comment: I agree that the documentation is a bit sparse (they have docs for integration RPM with RSP [here](https://docs.rstudio.com/rspm/admin/rstudio-server/#rstudio-server), for instance). I think this question is best asked on the RStudio community pages, though, since RStudio employees look at those and can answer authoritatively. Since you're using RSC, you should also have a contact with RStudio; I suggest after you ask on RStudio Community, you ping them as well (with the link to the community posting).

Answer (score 1):

Just to not leave the question without answer:

For RStudio Connect it is possible to configure the settings related to RStudio Package Manager in the main config file, by default is `/etc/rstudio-connect/rstudio-connect.gcfg`.

Example peace of config file:

```
; /etc/rstudio-connect/rstudio-connect.gcfg
[RPackageRepository "CRAN"]
URL = "https://cran-mirror.production.company.com/"

[RPackageRepository "CORPORATE"]
URL = "https://corporate-packages.production.company.com/"
```

This will equals to following command in R:

```
options(
  repos = c(
    CRAN = "https://cran.rstudio.com/",
    CORPORATE = "https://corporate-packages.development.company.com"
  )
)
```

Source: https://docs.rstudio.com/connect/admin/appendix/configuration/#RPackageRepository

Answer (score 0):

I work at RStudio and came across your post. This community is mainly for open source users, but for licensors of RStudio's professional products (like RStudio Connect, RStudio Server Pro, and Package Manager), your organization should also have a designated Customer Success Representative that can coordinate a discussion to explain these details to you. You can find the contact information here: https://rstudio.com/about/contact/

You can also file a support ticket here if you need more technical/configuration related guidance:https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/requests/new

We hope to hear from you soon!

- Lauren

Comment: Thank you, Lauren! I actually did file a support ticket shortly after this question and was quickly able to find answers to my questions. Great support and products!